# How to Successfully Restart a USB Modem without Reboot

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem

@jorge-castro

Continuing from "[How to successfully restart a network without reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95817/how-to-successfully-restart-a-network-without-reboot)"

Hello Jorge Castro

Thank you for your detailed response on the topic [how-to-successfully-restart-a-network-without-reboot].  The discussion there seems to come closest to addressing my problem.  (I'm beginning a new question because I don't have enough Reputation points to continue the earlier discussion with a "Comment")

PROBLEM: Although my situation is a little different, I would like to ask if you can help. 
Rather than a wired or a wireless network going down, I am using a USB modem (ZTE - MBlaze) in India. 
Each time it disconnects, the ONLY way that I can get it to reconnect (at least 80% of the time) is a complete RESTART.

SOLUTIONS TRIED: I tried both the suggestions in this strand, and in the link which you provided. 
 "sudo service network-manager restart"  as well as "sudo ifdown -a" / "sudo ifup -a" 
NEITHER WORKED - Only a complete restart will allow use of the modem

OTHER POSSIBILITIES: I can try a "reboot without actually shutting down" and/or "kexec" but it seems that for both of these I would have to close all applications.  They will only reduce the time, but not eliminate the inconvenience of a reboot.

QUESTION: Can you suggest other Terminal commands that could help?

Thank you!

Bryan

BTW -  System: Toshiba NB200 Intel Atom CPU N280 @ 1.66GHz x 2 
   Graphics - Unknown, OS 32-bit, Disk 16.8 GB 
 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some perseverance, the solutions suggested by Jorge in his earlier post [How to successfully restart a network without reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95817/how-to-successfully-restart-a-network-without-reboot) solved my problem. 
 Using 'sudo service network-manager restart' followed by 'sudo ifdown -a' and then 'sudo ifup -a' works on my Ubuntu 12.04 netbook. 
 It always takes time. Once the network has restarted, it may take several minutes to "rediscover" my USB modem.  
 Sometimes I have to repeat the process.  
 Still, reconnect this way is FAR better than closing all programs and restarting Ubuntu every time the internet link drops.