# How do I force mount a USB modem?

Tags: networking, usb, mount, suspend, usb-modem

**Summary**

My USB modem fails to get mounted sometimes. If it is after a reboot (and login), it gets mounted. If it is not after a reboot (after a wake from suspend, e.g.), it absolutely fails to get mounted. `lsusb` shows that the modem is being detected in all the cases.

See below for details.

**Normal Scenario**

I connect the USB modem (after reboot) after logging in, the modem get mounted and shown as a CDROM (why?) in the launcher (though the name appears correctly). After a few minutes, a message appears in the line of, Mobile Broadband  Network,
You are now registered on the home network. All I have to do is to connect using the (previously configured) mobile broadband network, and then I am online.

The above happens most of the time, with a few exceptions, when the modem does not appear in the launcher at all, see below.

**Alternative Scenario**

1. After a reboot and  normal log in (rarely),
2. After a wake from suspend (always),

The modem does not get mounted when inserted and does not appear in the launcher. And as a result the aforementioned message is not shown. The only way out of this is a complete reboot and trying my luck again.

However, if I issue `lsusb`, the output shows that the modem is indeed there,

```
......
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 19d2:1232 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
......
```

I have already tried the solution mentioned here, [How to Successfully Restart a USB Modem without Reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490334/how-to-successfully-restart-a-usb-modem-without-reboot), without avail. This one fails.

How do I force mount a USB modem?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04, fully upgraded.

**EDIT**

When the modem is *not* mounted without any error message or some such, the relevant lines in `/var/log/syslog` look like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B74TmWRXTZrhOVJvMk1NVmNraW8/view?usp=sharing). *(Since there are too many lines, I have put these as an external file.)*

Comment: It is always useful if you mention the Ubuntu version for anyone to understand and support your query. I've seen this in 10.04 til 12.04 if I recall as when it mounts as a CD ROM thus the device will not be usable as a modem. I'm not sure and old post that I have answered will give you a clue, but worth to look at > http://askubuntu.com/questions/414963/setting-up-beetel-bg64-3g-usb-modem-in-ubuntu-13-10-how-to/416200#416200

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the log?

```
Sep 27 22:26:17 masroor-ProBook usb_modeswitch[13534]: usb_modeswitch: add device ID 19d2:1232 to driver option
Sep 27 22:26:17 masroor-ProBook usb_modeswitch[13534]: usb_modeswitch: please report the device ID to the Linux USB developers!
```

I suggest that you read `man usb_modeswitch; man usb_modeswitch_dispatcher; less /usr/share/doc/usb-modeswitch/README.gz` to figure out how to "`add device ID 19d2:1232 to driver option`"